# PHP changing your page name

Tags: php, get

I have a portfolio that shows 3 rows of images in one page.
it is called portfolio.php.

I want to make it so when you will click on next button, it will go to the next page (portfolio2.php) with the same content, just different image URLs and rename that page to portfolio.php?page=2
but without using a pagination script.

Is there a way to change that pages name without using any advanced PHP script for paging?
Some friend told me to do this way:

```
<?php
// Get the page ID
    $page_id = $_GET['page'];

    // Create the page string
    $page_string = "images_page" . $page_id . ".php";

    // Include the page
    include($page_string);
?>
```

But im not to sure how as I am getting Internal server error with this script.

Is there any way to rename a specify page to something like portfolio.php?page=2 ? something like (location: ) or something..

I want to do it this way because I am really clueless with PHP.

Thank you.

Comment: look at the server's error log to see what's causing the 500 error.

Comment: Welcome to the world of exploitable code. You are wide open for being hacked instantly, due to using user provided data (`$_GET`) without any checks and sanitization.

Comment: But mate, I am dealing with pages not databases..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this....

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != '') {
   $pageno = $_GET['page']; /* Sanitize Here */
} else {
   /* You can redirect user to home page */
}

if(isset($pageno)) {
  if($pageno == '1') {
       /* Page 1 content */
  } elseif($pageno == '2') {
    /* Page 2 content */
  }
}
```

**Note**:- Always sanitize your data

Comment: @justderb I can't sanitize here, as he can as per his requirements, now what can be better and easier than this? (excluding sanitizing)

Comment: Well, if he adds more pages he is repeating a lot of syntax.  Your code will work, but I feel it could be more eloquent.  But, with him just now working with PHP, this is probably the best way for him to do it.

Comment: Im getting internal error from this script too... just opened a ticket to my web hoster.

So this is the easier way to do this?

Comment: The 500 internal server error could be caused for any number of reasons:

1.) The server has crashed or is under maintenance
2.) There is an error in your .htaccess file and the server does not know how to respond to your request
3.) There is a problem with the script that you are using

Usually the error logs can shed some light into the cause, but at this point, I can't find any reason why it does not work, so I would contact the script author for support

Comment: @user1761494 this is a basic script, can't see any errors in this

Comment: I can't use that code.. becasue I need to include a lot of classes and html per page, and i can echo that much of information, ill get syntax error.,

Comment: you don't need to echo, just close php brackets and write your html content, and again start your php brackets for php code